# Hiding filter based on user in Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a filter by different divisions (Management, IT, Finance, etc). I currently have it so that I can do data quality check for each division. However, I don't want this filter to show up users of different divisions. Right now, the IT folks can see the division filter and as they are restricted to see only their division's data, they only see the "IT" as the only option in the filter. I would like for them to not see the Division filter at all as it is not useful for them, but I do need it for data quality purposes.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to publish a workbook without the filter for the end users and another workbook with the filter just for you in a different folder (which only you can access). This one works always but you have 2 versions of the same report.

Or you can try it with parameters as described here:

https://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2017/01/26/hiding-parameters-filters-tableau/